# Django Testing: determine which view was executed

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-views, django-testing

In the Django [testing documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#module-django.test.client) they promise that you can "Test that the correct view is executed for a given URL."

However I didn't find any possibility how to test which view was executed. I would expect that in the [`Response` class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Response) but there's nothing about the executed view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the view function name thusly

```
from django.test.client import Client
c = Client()
response = c.get('/')
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
resolve(response.request["PATH_INFO"])[0].func_name
```

Comment: wow, this looks a little bit hackish, but yeah, it works. It uses the resolve function to get the matched url pattern. But there's no problem about that, because it's just the opposite way django works when resolving the URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dave's answer involves a HTTP request each time you're testing a url, which can be slow. If you just want to know what view a url resolves to, you can do that without using `Client`:

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver
>>> from myapp.views import func_to_test
>>> resolver = get_resolver(None)
>>> match = resolver.resolve('/some/path/')
>>> if match.func is func_to_test:
>>>    print "correct function for resolution!"
```

[Ryan Wilcox's post on route testing](http://blog.wilcoxd.com/blog/2012/07/30/testing-urls-in-django-like-rails-route-testing/) goes into more detail and provides techniques for making it even easier to test them.